# Setting CSS value limits of the window scrolling animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I have a <div id='map'> map that slides as the user scrolls down. However, it seems to let the map scroll forever, never letting the user actually reach the bottom of the page (there is a footer).

What I am trying to do is get the <div> to stop scrolling when it reaches the end of another dynamically-sized (height is variable) <div>. These two <div>s are side-by-side and in the same row.

Here is the JavaScript code I'm using to make the right div move with the user's scroll:

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $("#map"),
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        }
        else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's using Twitter Bootstrap. There is a Google Map with ID 'map' on the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use `animate()` method with scroll function it will create conflict because scroll value will change always and jQuery can not infinite repeat same animation. Stop won't rescue this issue either, or i cound't manage to do it.

And i [suggest to use variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872381/scrolltop-and-then-div-fixed/11872508#11872508) in `if` statements.

[Here is not working animate sample with animate usage.](http://jsfiddle.net/4TfTF/14/)

**[Here is same example working with css method.](http://jsfiddle.net/4TfTF/8/)**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( scrollVal > offset.top) {
        $sidebar.css({
           'margin-top': (($window.scrollTop() - offset.top) + topPadding) + 'px'
                       //added +'px' here to prevent old internet explorer bugs
        });
    } else {
        $sidebar.css({'margin-top':'0px'});
    }
});
```

Note: if you want to expand your if statements with `else if`, don't use `else`, it will create conflict too. Bealive me i am really expreienced with this issue.

**UPDATE:**

You can change your approuch to calculations of the limits too. I presume you want to fix the nav and your html is like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <span id="subnav">hold this</span>
</div>​
```

and jQuery calculations should be like this:
[Here is working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4TfTF/26/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var headerH = $('.header').outerHeight(true);
      //this will calculate header's full height, with borders, margins, paddings
       console.log(headerH);
       var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( scrollVal > headerH ) {
        //when scroll value reach to your selector
            $('#subnav').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px'});
        } else {
            $('#subnav').css({'position':'static','top':'0px'});
        }
    });
 });​
```

Comment: Now it does nothing. I feel it's because there is a variable issue. Ideas?

Comment: You got problems with calculations too mate, i updated my answer.