# Scrolling bar for messages like in Facebook messages

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook

Is it possible to make something like this:
[image: http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/1167/unbenannt1kopiel.png]
When the scroll bar is used, only the content from the div in which the messages are scrolls.
Does somebody know how to do this in css?

Comment: One way to do it is by using absolute positioning on everything EXCEPT the container that you want to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do this with pure css; [position property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp), no need jQuery.

Use css `position:fixed;` on element's you don't want to scroll and use css values `float:left;` or `position:relative;` on content areas you want to scroll.

But if you want to stick some element's according to `scroll.top` value, you need to use jQuery. I suggest to inspect these answer for it: [How to build simple sticky navigation at the page bottum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983294/make-div-stick-to-bottom-of-browser-then-top-of-browser-on-scroll/11983369#11983369)  and [Setting CSS value limits of the window scrolling animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971475/setting-css-value-limits-of-the-window-scrolling-animation/11971912#11971912)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I have the followin problem:
It shoud look like: http://jsfiddle.net/mkCsy/
But it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/ESF3P/
How I can fix the floatings?

Comment: if you gonna use `position` property, you need to define `top` and `left` values for positioning element. and don't forgot to define position:relative to wrapper for defining child element's baz position. did you want to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/ESF3P/6/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very possible. For the objects that shouldn't scroll, specify:

```
position: fixed;
```

in its CSS selector.