# Menu stick to bottom of browser then top of browser on scroll

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm trying to make menu-bar sticking to bottom of browser and to top of browser after scrolling. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983294/make-div-stick-to-bottom-of-browser-then-top-of-browser-on-scroll) but there is one thing - it doesn't work properly after resizing window. I mean, when bar is stick to top and you resize window everything is ok, but then you scroll up back and it's not sticking to bottom anymore... On the other hand when it's sticking to bottom and you resize window (eg. turn favourites bar on) it doesn't refresh.

Please help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {

   var WH = $(window).height();
   var fixBottom = WH - $('.menu-bar').outerHeight(true);

$('.menu-bar').css({'top': fixBottom + 'px'});   

   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( scrollPos > fixBottom ) {
        $('.menu-bar').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px'});
    } else {
        $('.menu-bar').css({'position':'absolute','top': fixBottom +'px'});
    }
});

});

});//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: I've got to believe there's a css-only solution out there for this...

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no css-only solution for this. Can anyone add appropriate part to code?

Comment: Oh come on! Please, help me with this issue. I know it's easy as pie for most of you:(