# Sticky NavBar onScroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm currently building a site for myself, and I found this really awesome effect on multiple sites where the navbar is below an image, but when you scroll past it, it sticks to the top.

[Example](http://www.littleco.com/)

How can I achieve this? Also, how can I achieve an effect similar to the one on [this website with a similar navbar style](http://riotdesign.eu/en/)?

Comment: Using javascript to check the scroll position and css positioning. Once the user scrolls past to or past the point where you want the navbar to stick to the top you can position the navbar using css position: fixed;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what @Matthew was talking about:

### Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/yp8HK/1/

### JQUERY

```
var num = 200; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Hope it helps, I used bootstrap navbar.

Comment: Side note; make sure you check which browsers support `position:fixed`: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed

Answer (score 1):

## Using jQuery

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
     jQuery(".header-sticky").toggleClass('fixed',jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 50);
});
```

```css
.fixed{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some few examples

With in bootstrap you can use `navbar-fixed-top` class.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

Have a look at following links:

Fixed to Top :  http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Fixed Navbar example : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Bootstrap 5 has a `sticky-top` class that can be used to create a static-to-fixed Navbar effect when the page is scrolled.

[Bootstrap 5 stick navbar after scrolling (simply sticky-top)](https://codeply.com/p/Gq9DKl9zNY)
[Bootstrap 5 stick navbar after scrolling (animate with IntersectionObserver)](https://codeply.com/p/wHQ6QdMkrV)

**Bootstrap 4 (update 2018)**

The Affix plugin was removed in Bootstrap 4 since CSS position: sticky accomplishes similar behavior. However, position: sticky won't animate the changing of the navbar style. For this an intersection observer can be used.

[See this question for Bootstrap 4 sticky navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237406/animate-shrink-navbar-on-scroll-using-bootstrap-4/42250478#42250478)

**Bootstrap 3 (original answer)**

Here's a Bootstrap example that attaches the navbar to the top once the user has scrolled past the top header using the Bootstrap 3 Affix plugin..

https://codeply.com/p/HAQSABYqPY

Comment: Thanks so much for the links! (: I love the animated one! I'll have to throw that in my site!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a REAL [quick example](http://codepen.io/Matthewnie/pen/ksKbh) I threw together with jquery and some very simple css.

JS

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>=95 && !$('nav').hasClass('fixed')){
        $('nav').addClass('fixed'); 
    }
    else if($(window).scrollTop()<95 && $('nav').hasClass('fixed')){
       $('nav').removeClass('fixed') 
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.container {
  height: 1800px;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  background-color: #efefef;
  border-top: 2px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x85" alt="" />
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of sticky navigation bar On-Scroll with dynamic height getting

### JS

You need to add a jQuery Library file first.

Here is fiddle link-
https://jsfiddle.net/CV_pawan/4nr4codq/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var num = $(".header-class").offset().top; 
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() { 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {  
      $('.header-class').addClass('fixed');  
    } 
    else {  
     $('.header-class').removeClass('fixed');    
    } 
  });
});
```

## CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav-bar-white {
  background-color: #125456;
  width: 100%;
}

.active-2 {
  float: right;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: right;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
}

.first {
  background: #000;
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.first p {
  color: #fff;
}

.second {
  background: #000;
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.second p {
  color: #fff;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #300E06;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

## HTML

```
<ul class="nav-bar-white">
  <li class="active-1"><a href="#home">Company Logo</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="header-class">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
  <div class="first">
    <h3>
What is Lorem Ipsum?
</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <h3>
What is Lorem Ipsum?
</h3>
    <p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="first">
  <h3>
What is Lorem Ipsum?
</h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <h3>
What is Lorem Ipsum?
</h3>
  <p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery users, check out :

```js
var yourNavigation = $(".nav");
    stickyDiv = "sticky";
    yourHeader = $('.header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > yourHeader ) {
    yourNavigation.addClass(stickyDiv);
  } else {
    yourNavigation.removeClass(stickyDiv);
  }
});
```

```css
/* google font */


body {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
}

.header {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  font-size:50px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.nav {
  width:100%;
  height:60px; 
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:60px; 
  background:#ff5252;
  color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:60px;
  z-index:3;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.content {
  width:640px;
  height:500vh;
  font-size:14px;
  padding-top:100px;
  margin:0 auto 0;
}

.sticky {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}

p {
  line-height:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="sticky.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sticky.css">

<body>
    <header class='header'>Header</header>
    <div class='nav'>Navigation</div>
    <div class='content'>
        <h1>Simple sticky navigation bar</h1>
        <p>Using jQuery we add (or remove) a sticky class to the navigation bar. The sticky class fixes the position.
        </p>
        <p>This happens whenever the page is scrolled. We check to see how far down the page has scrolled, if this
            number is greater than the height of the header, we add the sticky class to the navigation.</p>
        <p>You can already achieve this effect using only CSS with <b>position: sticky;</b> but it's not supported by
            many browsers at the moment.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add relevant code in your answer, answer with only link can be useless if link is broken