# how to create a sticky navbar css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a sticky navbar on scroll with CSS and JavaScript, but it's show as a normal navbar, and it's not sticking when scrolling. How can I make it stick when it is scrolling? i added the header to the code

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Navbar links */

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <h2>S I U</h2>
 <p>T h e  f u t u r e  &  B e y o n d</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: As you mentioned it, did you try some JavaScript?

Comment: You have `.sticky` as a selector in your CSS but you don't have that class anywhere in your HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sticky NavBar onScroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541364/sticky-navbar-onscroll)

Comment: Hmm, it's a little unclear what exactly you wish to accomplish. Would you please provide some specific details?

Comment: sure, check this out https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: Your code appears to work when I tried it... What problem are you having?

Comment: I want the navbar to be under the header and not start sticking at the top of the page unless i scrolled.

Comment: Perhaps it's simply a matter of inserting some content above your nav? Or possibly you have not set up your document correctly? Hard to say!

Comment: the header is now in my code

Comment: Do you have a sample of content underneath that would make the body scroll? From what I see, it works.

Comment: Yes, there is alot of content underneath it.

Comment: @Josephizz do you have a sample content you can share?

Comment: sure 
    `<div class="cb"> 
    <h2>Business Computing</h2>
    <p>The Business Computing BSc degree is a challenging course that provides highly relevant, hands-on experience. Through a mixture of theory and real-world practice, you’ll learn how to determine a dynamic mix of processes, which allow information delivery systems and users to carry out business effectively and efficiently. You’ll come to intuitively understand how an organisation’s information systems need to adapt to the changes and developments natural to growth and progress.</p>
   </div>`

Answer (score 3):

Almost there! You need to apply the `.sticky` class to your nav in order for it to stick.

```js
window.onscroll = function() { myFunction() };
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

```css
body {
   height: 10000px;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Navbar links */

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked, but now it's sticking in the top of the page not on scrolling.

Comment: well, i copied the code from 3w schools, and in their sample itsn't stick to the top untill you scroll https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: @Josephizz if that's the case, the full code is here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky

Comment: @astonearachnid same result :) ,still not sticking AFTER scrolling.

Comment: In which case you are correct to not apply the `sticky` class in your HTML. I have edited my answer to reflect this (with the code straight from the w3 resource)

Comment: well, after the changes it isn't sticking at all.

Comment: Are you, perchance, using Opera Mini? https://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20fixed

Comment: No , i'm using chromium Version 73.0.3663.0 (Developer Build) (32-bit)

Comment: And to be clear, when you run the snippet in my answer you do not observe a navbar which starts out static with an offset on the page and then "sticks" to the top upon scrolling down past the offset?

Comment: Just not in your document, I assume? Are you sure you've got everything syntactically correct? Javascript in `<script>` tag at the bottom of body, and all that?

Comment: Yes i double checked, and i tried javscript from a `script` and separeted file as well.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't applying your `.sticky` `class`. Add it to your navbar (I added a bunch of div's to force some scrolling)

```css
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Navbar links */

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="sticky">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
<div>Test to cause some stroll</div>
```

Comment: i want it to stick at the top of the page "after" scrolling only.

Comment: I see. In that case, create a javascript function to apply `.sticky` when a user scrolls. If they are at the top of the page, you can detatch the class.