# How do i make my nav bar static (fixed at the top of the page when scrolling down)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```
<div id="nav" class="ten columns">
<ul class="navb">
<li <?php if ($page == "#about"){ echo "class='active'";} ?> ><a href="#aboutintro">About</a></li>
<li <?php if ($page == "#portfolio"){ echo "class='active'";} ?> ><a href="#portintro">Portfolio</a></li>
<li <?php if ($page == "#content"){ echo "class='active'";} ?> ><a href="#contactintro">Contact</a></li>
<li <?php if ($page == "#home"){ echo "class='active'";} ?> ><a href="#homeintro">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

When i scroll down, i want the navbar at the top to stay fixed at teh top of the page. Here is my css i have up to now on the nav bar:

```
ul.navb li.active {
border-bottom: 2px solid #9EADFF;
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327505/navbar-stick-to-top-of-screen-when-scrolling-past

Comment: Unrelated, but you can change your PHP to something like this: http://pastebin.com/wuGx3zD3 

It just saves you from having to write it all out.

Comment: Have you tried giving `position:fixed` to #nav ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this i placed the example script there may be u need this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4EcFf/470/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var menu = $('.menu');
    var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;

    function scroll() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
            $('.menu').addClass('sticky');
            $('.content').addClass('menu-padding');
        } else {
            $('.menu').removeClass('sticky');
            $('.content').removeClass('menu-padding');
        }


    }

    document.onscroll = scroll;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have special requirements this is sufficient:

```
#nav{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```