# jQuery Horizontal scroll with hidden , possibly css only?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, scroll

I have a navigation menu that is very long consisting of 10 links.

What I need to do is have the links going across the page, then when you get near to the end of the navigation, you are presented with an option to scroll to across to see the other hidden links in the menu, then an option to scroll back.

I found something similar here, but need it horizontal.
http://jsfiddle.net/CxbYf/2/

If possible can this be done with CSS only? overflow hidden and scroll?

Any help would be great,

Thanks

Comment: this migth help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971475/setting-css-value-limits-of-the-window-scrolling-animation/11971912#11971912

Comment: you could use `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` if you just want the standard scrollbars from the browser, otherwise it will require some scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could

### *[THIS DEMO](http://jsbin.com/opufow/47/edit)*

and *THIS BIT OF JQUERY*:

```
$('.prv, .nxt').click(function(e){
  $(this).siblings('.slider').stop().animate({
    scrollLeft: (this.className.match('nxt')?'+=':'-=')+200
  },1000); 
});
```

solve your issue?