# jQuery / JavaScript: Check if number is greater than another number by a minimum amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that fires only if a user has scrolled left or right, by doing the following:

```
var currentScrollLeft = visibleArea.scrollLeft();

visibleArea.scroll(function () {
    var newScrollLeft = visibleArea.scrollLeft();

    if (newScrollLeft > currentScrollLeft) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

But this fires after even the slightest change in `scrollLeft`. Is there a way I can tell it to only fire if it's moved more than a certain amount, say `50`?

Comment: this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971475/setting-css-value-limits-of-the-window-scrolling-animation/11971912#11971912

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if((Math.abs(newScrollLeft - currentScrollLeft)) > 50)
```

So your code above would become:

```
var currentScrollLeft = visibleArea.scrollLeft();

visibleArea.scroll(function () {
    var newScrollLeft = visibleArea.scrollLeft();

    if (Math.abs(newScrollLeft - currentScrollLeft) > 50) {
        // do something
    }

    currentScrollLeft = visibleArea.scrollLeft();
});
```

Comment: this will only detect when scrolling right, can we also do the same when scrolling back the other way? What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @Owen this will work both ways, because Math.abs returns the absolute value of 50 regardless whether the difference is 50 (left) or -50 (right). Try it ;)

Comment: ahhh of course, I was using it wrong, I was appending it to my current if statement rather than replacing it.