# Get height of multiple divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to get the height of three divs, add them together and see if the scroll position is great than that number. Right now I am able to get the height of one element, but how could I add others in?

Basically, I want to write "if scroll_top is greater than the height of div 1 + div 2 + 3"

```
var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();

if ((scroll_top > $('.nav-bar-fixed').height()) {
    alert('sometext');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var limit =$('.myEle1').height() + $('.myEle2').height() + $('.myEle3').height();
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( scrollVal > limit ) {
           //do something.
        }
    });
 });​
```

[Here is a fixed nav sample](http://jsfiddle.net/4TfTF/26/) and [source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971475/setting-css-value-limits-of-the-window-scrolling-animation/11971912#11971912)

Answer (score 14):

Why not simply this ?

```
var h = 0;
$('#div1, #div2, #div3').each(function(){ h+=$(this).height() });
```

Comment: Saved me from writing it!

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick.

[Working example on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/eqahed/1/edit).

HTML:

```
  <div class="nav-bar-fixed"></div>
  <div class="nav-bar-fixed"></div>
  <div class="nav-bar-fixed"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-bar-fixed {
  height: 200px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(),
    $navBarFixed = $('.nav-bar-fixed'),
    totalHeight = 0;

$.each($navBarFixed, function() {
    totalHeight += $(this).height();
});

if (scroll_top > totalHeight) {
    alert(totalHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this JQuery based function:

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.sumHeights = function () {
      var h = 0;
      this.each(function() {
         h += $(this).height();
      });
      return h;
   };
})(jQuery);
```

And then call it like this:

```
$('div, .className, #idName').sumHeights();
```