# Using jQuery each, scrollTop() returns zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem using a jQuery `scrollTop()` function with `$.each.` Every time, no matter how many `<div class="panel"></div>` elements are, `scrollTop()` function returns zero. I've used code in the [Get height of multiple divs with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782087/get-height-of-multiple-divs-with-jquery) thread, only changed `height()` to `scrollTop()` function (`height()` still returns zero).

Here is the code that I've created, so it will be much easier to understand the problem.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}

var $panel = $('.panel'),
  totalHeight = 0;

$.each($panel, function() {
  totalHeight += $(this).scrollTop();
});

alert(totalHeight);
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Lėšų išsiėmimai</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>12 val.</th>
        <th>0.01 Eur</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>24 val.</th>
        <th>0.02 Eur</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td>2017-06-26 01:39:16</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td>2017-06-24 14:43:50</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2017-06-24 14:43:27</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>

        <td>2017-06-15 14:43:43</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2017-06-15 14:42:23</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>

        <td>2017-06-07 16:34:04</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2017-06-07 16:33:36</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>

        <td>1970-01-01 03:00:00</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2017-06-06 15:13:41</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>

        <td>1970-01-01 03:00:00</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background: #0E82A7;">Iš viso</td>
        <td style="background: #0E82A7;" colspan="2">0.0400 Eur</td>
        <td style="background: #0E82A7;"></td>
        <td style="background: #0E82A7;" colspan="2">0.1200 Eur</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>12 val.</th>
        <th>0.01 Eur</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>24 val.</th>
        <th>0.02 Eur</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td>2017-06-26 01:39:16</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td>2017-06-24 14:43:50</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2017-06-24 14:43:27</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>

        <td>2017-06-15 14:43:43</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2017-06-15 14:42:23</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>

        <td>2017-06-07 16:34:04</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2017-06-07 16:33:36</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>

        <td>1970-01-01 03:00:00</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2017-06-06 15:13:41</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>

        <td>1970-01-01 03:00:00</td>
        <td colspan="2">+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background: #0E82A7;">Iš viso</td>
        <td style="background: #0E82A7;" colspan="2">0.0400 Eur</td>
        <td style="background: #0E82A7;"></td>
        <td style="background: #0E82A7;" colspan="2">0.1200 Eur</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it will make a difference, but use `$panel.each()` when looping over a jQuery collection, not `$.each($panel)`

Comment: Also, why are you using a mix of jQuery and vanilla JS?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Some code was written by me, some no, i will fix it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly height property will return 0 as your panels are set to

```
max-height:0;
```

When the code runs. Now, the function:

```
scrollTop()
```

Will check the scroll of window, what you are probably looking for is:

```
$(this).offset().top
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/08gccLph/

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for efforts, I will check now :)