# Jquery move element on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example: I have menu horisontally (on header), then if I scroll page down (about >100px from top) the menu (horisontal) will move to left side of browser (vertical) and fixed there...

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

[Here is working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4TfTF/232/) and [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971475/setting-css-value-limits-of-the-window-scrolling-animation/11971912#11971912).

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

   var headerH = $('.header').outerHeight(true);
   //this will calculate header's full height, with borders, margins, paddings
   var scrollTopVal = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( scrollTopVal > headerH ) {
        $('#subnav').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px'});
    } else {
        $('#subnav').css({'position':'static','top':'0px'});
    }

   var scrollLeftVal = $(this).scrollLeft();
   if ( scrollLeftVal > 1 ) { alert('i scrolled to the left'); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks... can you give sample with menu horizontal to vertical onscroll?