# Animate Height - Else Not Working

Tags: jquery

Just the first "else" not working. topColor div will expand from original 15 high to 150 high when scrolling down, but not shrink back to 15 high when I scroll near the top.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
            $('#topColor').animate({
                height: "150px"
            });
        } else {
            $('#topColor').animate({
                height: "15px"
            });
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
            $("#fixedMenuBar").fadeIn('slow', 'linear');
        } else {
            $("#fixedMenuBar").fadeOut('fast', 'linear');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the value of $(this).scrollTop() ? have it log into the console with console.log($(this).scrollTop());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `else` in scroll responsed animations, use `else if` instead for being more specific and `animate` will create conflict because scroll value will change always and jQuery can not infinite repeat same animation.

But if you insist on `animate` try this:

```
    var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();

    if ( scrollVal < 20 )
      if ( $("#fixedMenuBar").is(':visible') ) {
        $("#fixedMenuBar").fadeOut('fast', 'linear');
      }
      if ( parseInt($('#topColor').css('height')) != 150 ) {
        $('#topColor').animate({ height: "150px" });
      }

    }else if ( scrollVal >= 20 && scrollVal < 300 ) {
      if ( $("#fixedMenuBar").is(':visible') ) {
        $("#fixedMenuBar").fadeOut('fast', 'linear');
      }
      if ( parseInt($('#topColor').css('height')) != 15 ) {
        $('#topColor').animate({ height: "15px" });
      }

    }else if ( scrollVal >= 300 ) {
       if ( !$("#fixedMenuBar").is(':visible') )
        $("#fixedMenuBar").fadeIn('slow', 'linear');
    }
```

This answer also should help you: [Setting CSS value limits of the window scrolling animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971475/setting-css-value-limits-of-the-window-scrolling-animation/11971912#11971912)

Comment: +1 and you should also check if the element `$().is(':animated')` to prevent a large animation query

Comment: Thank you...my first jquery attempt. I added your code...but now my site doesn't load. Wrapped it in $(document).ready(function () and $(window).scroll(function ().

Comment: I ended up just using .scrollTop with translateY to slide the object down and back. Easier for now. Thanks again for your time!