# How to have a floating vertical nav menu and have it adjust its position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I've been at this for awhile and I'm just stuck. I'm using Win XP, IE8, and JQuery 1.4.4.

What I want is that the nav menu starts under the header. But once the header is out of view, the nav menu will stay at the top of the scrolled window. When the user scrolls back up and header comes back into view, the nav menu should then stay under the header again.

Right now, it's floating but not adjusting the way I want it to.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Please make this scrolling work</title>
    <link href="Styles/Navigation.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                //var bottom = $('#contents').height() + 100;
                var bottom = $(window).height();
                var top = $('#header').height();
                var top_start = top + 1;
                var top_limit;
                if (document.body.scrollTop <= top_start) {
                    top_limit = top_start;
                }
                else {
                    top_limit = 0;
                }
                $('#menu-bar').css('top', (top_limit) + "px");
                //$('#menu-bar').css('bottom', (bottom) + "px");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="header" style="clear:both;height:40%;">
        stuff
        <br />
        <br />
        more stuff
        <br />
    </div>
    <div class="menu-bar" style="float:left;width:25%;" id="menu-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#mainpage">Main Page</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#foo">Foo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#bar">Bar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#baz">Baz</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#blah">Blah</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="contents" style="float:left;margin-left:25%;">
        olwqfjapnwvqjpfqjwfeoqjfepqfewjqpfjnqpefpkqjmewpofqne
        <br />
        powjunvejpqlewkjrvqpnewkjmqwofvjnewpfoqewkjponqejpewfmqewp
        <br />
    </div>
```

And the CSS for the menu:

```
.menu-bar{  
    position: fixed;
    overflow:scroll;
    height:100%;
    /*top:0;
    bottom:0;*/
}
```

**EDIT:**
This was the fix.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            //var bottom = $('#contents').height() + 100;
            var bottom = $(window).height();
            var top = $('#header').height();
            var top_start = top + 1;
            var top_limit;
            if ($(window).scrollTop() <= top_start) {
                top_limit = top_start;
            }
            else {
                top_limit = 0;
            }
            $('#menu-bar').css('top', (top_limit) + "px");
            $('#menu-bar').css('bottom', (bottom) + "px");
        });
    </script>
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Though I don't quite understand why:

```
top_limit = 0; //works but...
top_limit = $(window).scrollTop(); //doesn't work.
```

Comment: can you show us an online example ..

Comment: I've done this somewhere before... From what I can remember, look at `.offset()` and `.position()`

Comment: Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/9tSAJ/

Comment: This looks like its exactly what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408713/div-that-follows-scroll-not-positionfixed#7237089

Comment: Oddly enough, it's working now. It wasn't before. I guess it was a refresh issue. Or something.....  Actually I moved it to the bottom of the page (just above the form tag) and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need is to calculate how much space is there above the screen of the user.
you have to calculate that with

this

```
$(document).height() // this will give you the size of the whole document
```

this

```
window.innerHeight // this will give you the size of the screen
```

and this

```
window.pageYOffset // this will give you how much you had scrolled vertically
```

a long time a made a function in order to make a similar effect that you require, I was needing that the menu stay on top if the header is out of sight, the header was 200px

```
function scrollControl(){
    if(($(document).height() - (window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset))<=500){
        //what to do if the space below is 500px or less, for the footer
    }else if(window.pageYOffset>=200){
        //what to do if the space above is 200px or more, for the header
    }else{
        //what to do if the element was in the rest of the space
    }
}
```

this is an old code if you think there is a mistake please be kind, I hope this help you out.